# Difference between Backup and Import bookmatks in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser

Main usage of Backup/Restore and Import/Export in Firefox.

Difference between both of them in functionality wise.

Comment: You should ask here - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/get-community-support

Comment: Close Voters: Questions about key 'buntu applications - key being stuff that are installed by default, are On-Topic.

Comment: But firefox is not a key Ubuntu application >:-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

Backup/Restore it creates a .json file that you can use on FF only.

Import/Export it creates an HTML file that can be used with FF or other browsers.